# Display json string result in listview in android

Tags: android, json, android-listview

How to display JSON string result in Android `ListView`

Here is the JSON  string

```
[{"USER_ID":83,"PROJECT_BY_DETAILS":"An adaptation of a nursery rhyme into a dramatic film"},{"USER_ID":88,"PROJECT_BY_DETAILS":"Test - over ye mountain blue "}]
```

I need to display `USER_ID` and `PROJECT_BY_DETAILS` in a `ListView`

Comment: You should write more details, what exactly you want, Or better google it there are tons of guides

Comment: I need to display User id and PROJECT_BY_DETAILS in list view

Comment: You need an adapter for a listview, then put your json into the adapter and then put the adapter in your listview

Comment: Thank you..Can you show me how it is.

Comment: May be someone will write the code for doing all this, but what is really better for you is to find out by yourself. I'll just write the steps what you need to do to accomplish your goal, and you google them. In this way you will learn more. So the steps are following: 1) You should parse this JSON 2) After the parsing you will have `Array` or `ArrayList` or whataver you prefer to store data 3) Then you should use the adapter to populate this data into listview. There are difeerent types of adapters, like `ArrayAdapter` `BaseAdapter` etc. Choose which you like the most. Best regards =)

Comment: If you have JSONObject use GSON library..is the best.

Answer (score 0):

if you got this json from server - you can use retrofit for parsing information into object.
or you can use default android classes for parsing
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html
parse this json to arraylist of objects, and create listview adapter

Comment: String s=[{"USER_ID":83,"PROJECT_BY_DETAILS":"An adaptation of a nursery rhyme into a dramatic film"},{"USER_ID":88,"PROJECT_BY_DETAILS":"Test - over ye mountain blue "}].How to put this in list view

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Model to save your json Data
2. Create an Adapter
3. Use [Volley Library](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to do the request
4. Do the request using volley and save in your model
5. Notify your list that you have new data

A complete example of how to use volley with json in a list is [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)